# If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\gcd(a^2+b^2,a+2ab)=1$ or $5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The question is already in the title.

Show that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\gcd(a^2+b^2,a+2ab)=1$ or $5$.

I saw yesterday this exercise in a book and I tried many things but I managed  to show only that if some prime $p$ ($p$ must be $\equiv1\pmod{4}$)
divides $a^2+b^2$ and $a+2ab$ then    $p\mid2b+1$ , $p\mid4a^2+1$ and $p\mid b-2a^2$ but all these seem pointless.
Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Almost surely $\,a+2ab\,$ should be $\,a+2b,\,$ then it is correct. Double check the source (possibly a misprint).

Comment: @BillDubuque actually the next exercise suggests to prove the converse and it also has a typo there.Anyway if it was actually $a+2ab$ , $a$ would be immediately as a common factor excluded and this seems a little bit clumsy from the author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't a=9, b=19 a counter example?

Answer (score 4):

This is false. A counter-example is $a=2, b=25$ with 
$$\gcd(a^2+b^2, a+2ab)=\gcd(629, 102)=17$$
Other small counter-examples are the pairs:
$(4,19), (9,19), (15,8), (17,6), (17,19), (19,8).$

**Edit:** Playing around with my code, I numerically verified  for $1 \le a,b \le 10000$ the slightly changed statement:
If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\gcd(a^2+b^2,a+2b)=1$ or $5$.

Comment: Lol so there is a typo in the exercise.I was sure this was the case....

Comment: @Konstantinos Gaitanas: Seems to be a typo, see the edit addition to my answer.

Comment: Yes there was an answer -proof for this case before I know but it was deleted

Answer (score 2):

suppose $gcd(a,b)=1$ and let $d=gcd(a^2+b^2,a+2b)$

the identity

$(a^2+b^2)+(a+2b)(2b-a)=5b^2$

shows that $d$ divides $5b^2$ and

since $5a^2=5(a^2+b^2)-5b^2$ , $d$ divides $5a^2$

since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, $d$ divides $5$